# How to build a user profile on OpenID

Tags: php, authentication, openid

I want to use OpenID on my website and I understand how the external parts work but how do I take that user information and give my users an identity on my own website?  I am planning on using a PHP library like: [lightopenid](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/w/list) for the library.  Any suggestions or resources that I can check out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LightOpenID, `$openid->identity` will be unique identity to store in database.

And some OpenID Provider(OP) like [google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#Parameters) support [AX extensions](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html), that I use it to build up user profile by getting their first name (to address them in the future) and email (for contact) and store it in database.

And [LightOpenId](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/wiki/GettingMoreInformation) already support AX extensions. Example:

```
//required attribute(s)
$openid->required = array('namePerson/first', 'contact/email');

//optional attribute(s)
$openid->optional = array('namePerson/last');
```

If OP does not support AX, you can let user to choose their desire name, like SO currently does.

Some good resource I refer to when integrating LightOpenId:

- [How to make people login into your website with their Google account](http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/)
- [Log-in/log-out user status with LightOpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560940/log-in-log-out-user-status-with-lightopenid)